# How to create an array inside a Laravel collection

Tags: laravel, collections

I am using Laravel 7.
I need to retrieve al the projects that have many teams working on it.

This is the code that I have written in the controller method:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::select('projects.id as id', 'projects.name as name', 'teams.name as team_name')
            ->leftJoin('tasks', 'projects.id', '=', 'tasks.project_id')
            ->join('task_user', 'tasks.id', '=', 'task_user.task_id')
            ->join('users', 'task_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->join('teams', 'users.team_id', '=', 'teams.id')
            ->orderBy('projects.id')
            ->distinct()
            ->get();

        foreach ($projects as $key => $value) {
            $projects_length = $projects->where('id', $value['id'])->count();
            if($projects_length === 1) {
                unset($projects[$key]);
            }
        }

        $projects = $projects->values();

        return $projects;
}
```

The data format that I return as `$projects` is the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Creating new app with Symfony",
        "team_name": "Warriors"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Creating new app with Symfony",
        "team_name": "Guardians"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Creating new app with Vue.js",
        "team_name": "Warriors"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Creating new app with Vue.js",
        "team_name": "Reds"
    }
]
```

As you can imagine it's difficult to work with a similar response data format.
I would like to enclose the `team_name` data into an array, as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Creating new app with Symfony",
        "team_name": 
            [
                "Warriors",
                "Guardians"
            ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Creating new app with Vue.js",
        "team_name": 
            [
                "Warriors",
                "Reds"
            ]
    }
]
```

Can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
collect([
    [
        "id"=> 2,
        "name"=> "Creating new app with Symfony",
        "team_name"=> "Warriors"
    ],
    [
        "id"=> 2,
        "name"=> "Creating new app with Symfony",
        "team_name"=> "Guardians"
    ],
    [
        "id"=> 3,
        "name"=> "Creating new app with Vue.js",
        "team_name"=> "Warriors"
    ],
    [
        "id"=> 3,
        "name"=> "Creating new app with Vue.js",
        "team_name"=> "Reds"
    ]
])->groupBy('id')->map(function($data, $id) {
  return [
    'id' => $id,
    'name' => $data[0]['name'],
    'team_nameS' => $data->pluck('team_name')->toArray()
  ];
})->values()->toArray()
```

One way of doing it. Maybe you can look into using eloquent methods `with` and `whereHas` etc to solve most of this already at the query.

#### Output

```
=> [
     [
       "id" => 2,
       "name" => "Creating new app with Symfony",
       "team_nameS" => [
         "Warriors",
         "Guardians",
       ],
     ],
     [
       "id" => 3,
       "name" => "Creating new app with Vue.js",
       "team_nameS" => [
         "Warriors",
         "Reds",
       ],
     ],
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using GROUP_CONCAT with group by in your eloquent. I have not run it on my query browser but you can verify once and share the log, to check any further errors.

```
    $projects = Project::select('projects.id as id')
        ->leftJoin('tasks', 'projects.id', '=', 'tasks.project_id')
        ->join('task_user', 'tasks.id', '=', 'task_user.task_id')
        ->join('users', 'task_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('teams', 'users.team_id', '=', 'teams.id')
        ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(projects.name) as name', 'GROUP_CONCAT(teams.name) as team_name')
        ->groupBy('projects.id')
        ->orderBy('projects.id')
        ->get();
```

Comment: I receive the following error: `TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::selectRaw() must be of the type array, string given`. By the way, is your query risky about SQL injection?